# How to use term query when the keyword type is text in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi i have created an mapping in elasticsearch for claimnumber field when i use to search the term using term query it's working fine for text full of numbers but not working for the text combination of alphabet and numbers for example working for **"123456"** not working for **"CL123456"**

**mapping below**

```
{
  "duckcreek" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
          "claimnumber" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
          "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "policynumber" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "url" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**working for numbers**

```
GET duckcreek/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "claimnumber": {
        "value": "99520"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**not working text with numbers**

```
GET duckcreek/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "claimnumber": {
        "value": "CL123456"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly suggest a solution to resolve this?

Comment: thank u for accepting the answer  Can u please upvote the answer also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While performing an analysis on the text string using [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "CL123456"
}
```

The tokens generated are:

```
       {
            "tokens": [
                {
                    "token": "cl123456",
                    "start_offset": 0,
                    "end_offset": 8,
                    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
                    "position": 0
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title.keyword": {     <-- note this
        "value": "CL123456"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "matchprase1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "title": "CL123456"
        }
      }
    ]
```